# Can i know how to fix this error? is delete method

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Third {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
        String humanName; 

        humanName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the file name");
        File file = new File(+ humanName".txt");
        System.out.println(file.delete());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File deleted" + humanName);
    }

}
```

Comment: File file = new File(+ humanName".txt");


is stuck here, it suppose to read my input and delete the file i wan to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this line looks suspicious to start with:

```
File file = new File(+ humanName".txt");
```

Did you mean:

```
File file = new File(humanName + ".txt");
```

It's hard to say how to fix "this error" when you don't say what the error is, and the "is delete method" of your title doesn't make sense either.